# File download problem: filename with spaces truncated!

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

While I am working on code to download file from server using :

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
Server.UrlPathEncode(Path.GetFileName(_Filename)));
```

The problem is while having spaces in the file name,  with this code the server split automatically while finding the first space!

I'm hoping to know Why & what is the solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution :)

We have to surround the filename with double quotation mark like :

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(_Filename) + "\"");

But up till now, I didn't have any idea for this split?

Answer (score 42):

You need to wrap the filename in double quotes.

```
string filename = Server.UrlPathEncode(Path.GetFileName(_Filename)));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

Otherwise the code assumes that the filename ends at the first space.

You might not need the `Server.UrlPathEncode`.

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting the file name and not encoding it like so

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(_Filename) + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the case with firefox..

I found an answer by Alfonso Martinez here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221028#c1

> [Alfonso Martinez] was talking about this issue in #mozillazine with Christian
>   Biesinger and Boris Zbarsky, and they said that this is the proper behaviour
>   according to the RFC.
>
> The solution it's just to put the quoted filename and then everything will work
>   fine as that is the expected syntax.