# Valid filenames (for download) in IE?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, http, unicode

I have an action in aspnet mvc that returns a FileContentResult. I have noticed that when the fileDownloadName contains umlauts (ie åäöü) Internet Explorer can't read the file name at all.

I have tried UrlEncoding:

```
return this.File(document.Content, contentType, Server.UrlEncode(document.Name));
```

but then all spaces are replaced by plus signs (+).

**Is there a way to get unicode file names work with IE (keeping the original file name intact)?**

This is what I'm currently using as a hack:

```
return this.File(
    document.Content, 
    contentType, 
    Server.UrlEncode(document.Name).Replace('+',' '));
```

(This renders space as an underscore in IE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `UrlEncode` is misleadingly-named, it is only for form data. You would want `UrlPathEncode` instead which would solve the `+` problem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700721/does-urldecode-handle-plus-correctly) for background.
2. However in any case URL-encoding is the wrong thing to do here, as you aren't constructing a URL. The fact that it works in IE is a bug, which is why you get `%`-sequences in other browsers.

Unfortunately, there is no reliable cross-browser way to get non-ASCII characters into a `Content-Disposition` filename parameter. In theory it might have been possible using RFC 2331 rules, but even then the spec is arguable and the reality is nothing supports it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695719/18936) for background.

> Is there a way to get unicode file names work with IE (keeping the original file name intact)?

Drop the `filename` parameter from the `Content-Disposition` header and instead include the filename as a trailing path part of your script's address, where it's quite valid to use URL-encoding (UTF-8 and `UrlPathEncode`). eg for `someaction` controller:

```
http://www.example.com/someaction/åäöü.txt
http://www.example.com/someaction/%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC.txt
```

All browsers will offer to save the resulting file as `åäöü.txt`.

Comment: This causes a problem if the browser has a built in plugin to open that file type (for instance - PDFs). In that scenario the file will not be saved, but instead automatically opened inside the browser, which might not be the desired behavior.

Comment: @Tom: You can still pass a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, just without the `filename` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For responses I use solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736554/file-download-problem-filename-with-spaces-truncated). Maybe you could try to use it like

```
return this.File(
  document.Content,
  contentType,
  "\"" + Server.UrlEncode(document.Name) + "\"");
```

or

```
return this.File(
  document.Content,
  contentType,
  "\"" + document.Name + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the file name the way you do, but then replace all `+` with `%20`. Untested, but should work.

Comment: Works fine in IE but now in chrome the file name contains %2b where the space previously was.

Comment: How about replacing the `+` with spaces again? That should be allowed, as it's a ANSI character. You could as well try the code provided in one of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the encoding stuff, worked well in Chrome and FF, but had trouble with IE. 
So I just came up with my own cleaning routine. Basically it's just a mapping table, since we don't just want to remove all special chars.

```
//http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html
private static string[,] CharacterReplacements = { 
    { " ", "-"},
    { "&", "-"},
    { "?", "-"},
    { "!", "-"},
    { "%", "-"},
    { "+", "-"},
    { "#", "-"},
    { ":", "-"},
    { ";", "-"},
    { ".", "-"},

    { "¢", "c" },   //cent
    { "£", "P" },   //Pound
    { "€", "E" },   //Euro
    { "¥", "Y" },   //Yen
    { "°", "d" },   //degree
    { "¼", "1-4" }, //fraction one-quarter
    { "½", "1-2" }, //fraction half    
    { "¾", "1-3" }, //fraction three-quarters}
    { "@", "AT)"}, //at                                                  
    { "Œ", "OE" },  //OE ligature, French (in ISO-8859-15)        
    { "œ", "oe" },  //OE ligature, French (in ISO-8859-15)        

    {"Å","A" },  //ring
    {"Æ","AE"},  //diphthong
    {"Ç","C" },  //cedilla
    {"È","E" },  //grave accent
    {"É","E" },  //acute accent
    {"Ê","E" },  //circumflex accent
    {"Ë","E" },  //umlaut mark
    {"Ì","I" },  //grave accent
    {"Í","I" },  //acute accent
    {"Î","I" },  //circumflex accent
    {"Ï","I" },  //umlaut mark
    {"Ð","Eth"}, //Icelandic
    {"Ñ","N" },  //tilde
    {"Ò","O" },  //grave accent
    {"Ó","O" },  //acute accent
    {"Ô","O" },  //circumflex accent
    {"Õ","O" },  //tilde
    {"Ö","O" },  //umlaut mark
    {"Ø","O" },  //slash
    {"Ù","U" },  //grave accent
    {"Ú","U" },  //acute accent
    {"Û","U" },  //circumflex accent
    {"Ü","U" },  //umlaut mark
    {"Ý","Y" },  //acute accent
    {"Þ","eth"}, //Icelandic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)
    {"ß","ss"},  //German

    {"à","a" },  //grave accent
    {"á","a" },  //acute accent
    {"â","a" },  //circumflex accent
    {"ã","a" },  //tilde
    {"ä","ae"},  //umlaut mark
    {"å","a" },  //ring
    {"æ","ae"},  //diphthong
    {"ç","c" },  //cedilla
    {"è","e" },  //grave accent
    {"é","e" },  //acute accent
    {"ê","e" },  //circumflex accent
    {"ë","e" },  //umlaut mark
    {"ì","i" },  //grave accent
    {"í","i" },  //acute accent
    {"î","i" },  //circumflex accent
    {"ï","i" },  //umlaut mark
    {"ð","eth"}, //Icelandic
    {"ñ","n" },  //tilde
    {"ò","o" },  //grave accent
    {"ó","o" },  //acute accent
    {"ô","o" },  //circumflex accent
    {"õ","o" },  //tilde
    {"ö","oe"},  //umlaut mark
    {"ø","o" },  //slash
    {"ù","u" },  //grave accent
    {"ú","u" },  //acute accent
    {"û","u" },  //circumflex accent
    {"ü","ue"},  //umlaut mark
    {"ý","y" },  //acute accent
    {"þ","eth"}, //Icelandic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)
    {"ÿ","y" },  //umlaut mark
    };
```

I've wrapped it into a function, you can find the code here:
http://remy.supertext.ch/2012/08/clean-filenames/